# Why tan(1/z) has a non-isolated singularity at z=0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry

Can someone please explain me this concept. Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand the problem?

Comment: Write down the power series expansion. You will see that it is neither removable, nor a pole.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, it's non-isolated; by definition, it isn't a removable/pole/essential singularity.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan here is the expansion: tan(1/z) = 1/z + 1/3z^3 +2/15z^5 + . . . .  Ok i get it now , since all of the terms are still undefined at z=0 therefore.

Comment: @Ownage careful: a Laurent-like series never converges at the singularity, regardless of whether it's isolated. This is a quite different question: show that in each neighborhood of $z=0$ there exists some other singularity of $\tan\frac{1}{z}$.

Comment: @Ownage: Where are the singularities of $\tan(1/z)$?

Answer (score 10):

Note that $\tan z$ has poles at $z = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi k$ for every integer $k$. Hence $\tan(1/z)$ has a pole at every point where
$$
\frac1z = \frac{\pi}2 + \pi k \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad z = \frac{2}{\pi(1+2k)}.
$$
As $k\to\infty$, we get a sequence of poles tending to $z=0$, so by definition $z=0$ is *not* an isolated singularity (every neighbourhood of $z=0$ contains infinitely many other singularities).